producing an arrow on the terminal
So i want to produce this in the terminal
       #
      ###
     #####
    #######
   #########
  ###########
 #############
       H       
       H       
       H   

Hello , I'm new to stack overflow here and also to programming ,I'm a new cs student and my teacher gave us this small work to do to produce the image above on the terminal ,of course i can print the individual lines and get the result but i want to search for other ways. I've tried one method(the code below) and it works but i was wondering if there are more efficient way to do it. Again I'm new here and to programming if I'm being dumb or breaking any rules on here, I'm really sorry. Also if there are extra tips on how to use stack overflow or anything else ,pls share. Thank you very much.
tag = "#"
space = " "
x = 7
for i in range(1,15,2):
 print(space*x + tag*i)
 x=x-1 
for k in range(3):
 print(space*7 + "H" + space*7)

here is my code

https://codereview.stackexchange.com?

You could use f-strings with centering syntax:
width = 13
for i in range(1, width+1, 2):
    print(f"{'#'*i:^{width}}")
for _ in range(3):
    print(f"{'H':^{width}}")

Output:
      #      
     ###     
    #####    
   #######   
  #########  
 ########### 
#############
      H      
      H      
      H      


If you ask me, it's a bit neater to do the first loop like this:
for i in range(x):
    print(space*(7-i) + tag*(i*2+1))

I like it because here, the i is purely the row number, and then everything is calculated from that.
In the second loop, it's pointless to print the ending spaces. So just do:
for k in range(3):
    print(space*7 + "H")

One more thing is that there's not really a reason to use different variable names when it comes to the second loop. That's something you do when you have nested loops. And you could give some variables better names. Here is a suggestion:
tag = "#"
space = " "
x=7
for row in range(x):
    print(space*(x-row) + tag*(row*2+1))
for _ in range(3):
    print(space*x + "H")

row is a better name, and _ is common to use when the variable is not used in the loop.

Would re-use x for the last loop as well. The tail of the arrow will always have the same indent as the point. print(space*x + "H")

@flakes That's right. Fixed it.

You could try only using one for loop and just loop through the rows, and then once you reach a certain row number just print H. That would look something like  this.
tag = '#'
space = ' '
for row in range(10):
    if row < 7:
        print(space * (7 - row) + tag * (2 * row + 1))
    else:
        print(space * 7 + 'H')

This is basically the same thing just a bit of a different format. Another good thing to try is to compact the code as much as you can (good practice, never actually write code like that). Another slightly more advanced way would be to use a generator function and the yield keyword. Here's an example of that:
def make_arrow():
    for i in range(7):
        yield ' ' * (7 - i) + '#' * (2 * i + 1)
    for i in range(3):
        yield ' ' * 7 + 'H'


for x in make_arrow():
    print(x)

